# Xamarin Forms Bind command outside ItemSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90" ItemTapped="device_Clicked">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteDevice}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
            Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The ListView is bound to a List with objects in it, but I need to bind the command to an ICommand outside the List on root level of the ViewModel. How can I do that, because now the ICommand doesn't get triggered when I try to remove an item from the List!

Here is my Command in my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand DeleteDevice
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<int>((x) => RemoveDevice_Handler(x));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MenuItem.BindingContext` is scoped to the actual item in that cell, not the view model of the whole page (or `ListView`). You will either need to tell the binding that it needs to looks else where, like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteDevice, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}}"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note that I removed the attributes that you have in there just to make clear which ones I added. You can keep them in, this is just for readability.

Or, you can use the new [Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings). Then you would implement the command binding like this:

`Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:YourViewModelClass}}, Path=DeleteDevice}"`

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` that you are trying to bind with from the `Command` is not the `Page`'s one but the `ItemSource`, This is why you can simply bind the `Id` to the `CommandParameter`.

To fix this, you need to target the page's `BindingContext` since your `Command` lives at the ViewModel root level. You can achieve it by adding a `x:Name` property to your `ListView` and target the right `Context` through it.

Here the fix:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90" ItemTapped="device_Clicked">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions> 
                        <MenuItem Command = "{Binding BindingContext.DeleteDevice, Source={x:Reference listView}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                            Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True"  />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                </ViewCell>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```